# Juju node is eating up a lot of memory

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

my Juju node is consuming more than 90% of its RAM.

```
$ free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3953       3843        109          0        131       3229
-/+ buffers/cache:        482       3471
Swap:         3952          0       3952
```

Here's the output of `$ ps aux` http://paste.ubuntu.com/15601893/

Any help would be much appreciated.